# SQL 2008 R2 standard vs enterprise

Tags: infrastructure, licensing, sql

From a SharePoint Enterprise perspective what do you miss If you use SQL Standard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following whitepaper details all enterprise-only features and how they are used with SharePoint:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc990273.aspx

It also includes a table that relates SQL Server editions with SharePoint functions.

The most complete overview of SQL Server features can be found at

http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/product-info/compare.aspx

Answer (score 0):

For a more comprehensive, and interactive, list, check out http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/en-us/buy/Pages/Editions-Comparison.aspx

Comment: It's a nice link, but if you read the question, it's not about SharePoint Editions, but SQL Editions ;-) Thanks Anyway

Comment: LOL, sorry about that...